# Block unknown users in Pidgin

Tags: linux, instant-messaging, pidgin, opensuse, opensuse-11.2

How can I block messages from people who isn't in my buddy list in Pidgin?
I always receive a lot of bothering messages from people who is not in my list, I have look at  all the options in Pidgin but I didn't find where to set this condition.

Comment: Which protocol are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should be able (when logged-in to an account) to go to `Tools` > `Privacy` and select `Allow only the users on my buddy list`. However, there seems to [disparity](http://pidgin.im/pipermail/support/2008-September/002173.html) about how this is implemented for each of the protocols (although that reference is quite old). The Pidgin wiki does have [a list](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartyPlugins#SecurityandPrivacy) of third party plugins, such as Bot Sentry, which may help to properly implement this feature.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the "privacy" option when I was looking for this =S